# Japanese text is unrecognizable in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: utf-8, localization, phpmyadmin

I am phpMyAdmin, why is Japanese text in tables unrecognizable? However, I can output the Japanese text from the tables and it can be displayed correctly. Any idea? How to fix phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have wrongly set encoding in table structure and phpMyAdmin uses this information. What encoding you see configured for columns in table structure?

[MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html) on this topic might help you to fix this.